# Get first comment from YouTube using api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I could find the best way to get the first comment from a YouTube video. I could get all the comments and try but what if there is 30k comments. Help me.

Help me for this with python.

Comment: you can get the first comment if you got a 30k comments list.

Comment: I need to get the list using api.

Comment: you can use web scraping for getting comments from youtube.

Comment: Help me doing web scraping with python.

Comment: When you are dealing with Core Javascript featured website then Selenium would be the best choice. otherwise When it comes to a small project, Or low-level complex project Beautiful Soup can do the task pretty amazing. you can check https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Isn't there a better way than this one which is not resource hungry.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara I don't think Selenium would be the best choice, because the point of an api is that it doesn't need a browser to communicate and you don't have to scrape it like a html page.

Comment: Google has made some snippets for a lot of programming languages. I think [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets?apix=true) snippet will help you.

Comment: There is no option of sorting it by date

Comment: There is. The API explorer for `CommentThreads` shows an `order` parameter, which can sort by `time`. Why don't you show us the code you've already written and where you are experiencing difficulties so that we can help better?